# custom navigation for different user using core UI Angular template but I am getting some weird error in console

Tags: angular, core-ui

AppSidebarNavItemsComponent.html:33 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at createUrlTree (router.js:1902)
    at Router.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.Router.createUrlTree (router.js:4220)
    at AppSidebarNavLinkComponent.push../node_modules/@coreui/angular/fesm5/coreui-angular.js.AppSidebarNavLinkComponent.ngOnInit (coreui-angular.js:1317)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22494)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:31090)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:31052)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:31686)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:31646)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppSidebarNavItemsComponent.html:33)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:31638)

Comment: Same here. Trying to switch `navItems` with another array works but outputs this array in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the issue for me was how the navigation items were incorrectly defined.

Make sure that items with no URL are properly marked as either `divider: true` or `title: true`

The problematic element for me was:

```
{
    name: 'HELLO'
}
```

Changed it to:

```
{
    name: 'HELLO',
    title: true
}
```

No more console error, I can change items all I want without errors.