# Binding an array to a component in template is working only on page load

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular-services, angular9

I have a component (for a navigation bar) that is in my layout template and I'm using an injectable service so components can change the content of the navigation bar depending on their own logic.

Here's part of the template markup

**default-layout.component.html**

```
<app-sidebar-nav [navItems]="defaultLayoutService.items$ | async" [perfectScrollbar] [disabled]="appSidebar.minimized"></app-sidebar-nav>
```

**default-layout.component.ts**

```
constructor(public defaultLayoutService: DefaultLayoutService) {
}
```

**default-layout-service.ts**

```
import { navItems, ICustomNavData } from '../../_nav';

items$: Observable<ICustomNavData[]>;
navItems = <ICustomNavData[]>navItems; //cast to a custom interface I created.

setNavItemAttribute(itemKey: string, itemAttribute: string, text: string) {
    let menuItem = this.navItems.find(r => r.key == itemKey);

    if (menuItem && menuItem.hasOwnProperty(itemAttribute)) {
        menuItem[itemAttribute] = text;
    }

    console.log(this.navItems); //this outputs the items and shows they were modified correctly
    this.items$ = new Observable(ob => { ob.next(this.navItems); })

}
```

So I have components who also have access to `DefaultLayoutService` and call `setNavItemAttribute` with different parameters.

It works, but only when I refresh the page. When browsing in single app page mode, triggering a call to `setNavItemAttribute` with different parameters, the navigation items remain the same.

Am I handling the Observable correctly here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I handling the Observable correctly here ?

I see 2 potential problems here:

1. You're setting the `items$` Observable in your service to a new instance each time you update the corresponding item in the current array.
2. You're setting the value of that Observable to the same instance of the array, so Angular's change detection doesn't think the array has changed (even though values *within* it have).

---

Let's address those:

You can use an intermediary `Subject` to trigger values being emitted on the `Observable` from within your service, and call `.next` on it, when you want to update the values.

You do this by exposing the `Observable` as normal, built from the `Subject`. This is to prevent external influences being able to inadvertently/maliciously call `.next` directly on the subject.

Would look something like this:

```
export class DefaultLayoutService {
  private _navItems: <ICustomNavData[]>;
  private readonly _itemsSubject = new Subject<ICustomNavData[]>();

  items$: Observable<ICustomNavData[]> = this._itemsSubject.asObservable();

  setNavItemAttribute(itemKey: string, itemAttribute: string, text: string) {
    // code to update corresponding item in navItems array
    
    this._itemsSubject.next(this.navItems);
  }
}
```

Because the `Observable` is sourced from the `Subject`, it will emit the latest value you passed to the Subject in your service method.

Be aware that you will need to call `.next` with the first value to the `_itemsSubject`, when you first initialize the component and the array, so it can be emitted on the `Observable`.

---

> When browsing in single app page mode, triggering a call to setNavItemAttribute with different parameters, the navigation items remain the same.

Because the reference to the array *itself* hasn't changed, Angular's change detection doesn't re-render with the new values inside the array. Seems to be a common problem people stumble across.

A way I've done this before is to use the `...` spread operator to create a "new" array, using the old one. This way, the reference is different, and triggers the change detection to re-render using the new values.

Like so:

```
setNavItemAttribute(...) {
  // code to update the corresponding item in the existing _navItems array
  const navItemsCopy = [...this._navItems];

  // use the new array reference to trigger change detection
  this._itemsSubject.next(navItemsCopy);
}
```

There are many more ways to do this, so have a look around and see what fits your situation best and feels right for you.

Comment: Your solution works great. Struggled making it work because one of the items was improperly defined and made the component fail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138035/custom-navigation-for-different-user-using-core-ui-angular-template-but-i-am-get/61525499#61525499